# Is there an AlexNet model written with tensorflow without pre-trained weights?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been looking for AlexNet  models written on tensor-flow, and all I found was codes using some pre-trained weights already.

Do you have any idea if there exist code in which weights are built during the execution of the model ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a nice article here:[Finetuning AlexNet with TensorFlow](https://kratzert.github.io/2017/02/24/finetuning-alexnet-with-tensorflow.html)
It contains the address of the github code

Answer (score 2):

You can find a definition of the AlexNet model in TensorFlow in the path [`tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/alexnet.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/alexnet.py) of the TensorFlow repository (among the examples of what used to be TF-Slim and now is just `tf.contrib.layers`).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [here](https://github.com/paniabhisek/AlexNet) with a link to the [model](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14olIl-cxSpXovDkhxZglcx9jDVEcVP2E). But you can always train from scratch and check yourself.

**Note**: This only runs for 30 or so epochs(atleast at the time of writing) with less accuracy then claimed in paper. But you can always tweak learning rate and run for more epochs to get better accuracy.